# Creating A MultiSeries Bar Chart With Different Number of Series For Each Item

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm currently using highcharts on a project and having a hard time creating a chart I need.  I've researched this quite a bit and I don't think highcharts will be able to render the data the way I'm trying and I might need to split this into multiple charts which would be a 'hacky' way of accomplishing what I would like to do.

```
var mockData = [
{
    name: 'Southwest',
    partners: ['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4', 'E5'],
    data: [23, 42, 67, 53]
},{
    name: 'Delta',
    partners: ['F6', 'G7'],
    data: [55, 32]
},{
    name: 'American Airlines',
    partners: ['H8', 'I9', 'J10', 'K11', 'L12', 'M13'],
    data: [7, 25, 14, 78, 31, 55]
},{
    name: 'China Air',
    partners: ['N14', 'O15', 'P16', 'Q17', 'R18'],
    data: [1, 65, 35, 46, 74]
},{
    name: 'Air Mexico',
    partners: ['S19', 'T20', 'U21', 'V22', 'W23', 'X24', 'Y25', 'Z26', 'AA27', 'AB28', 'AC29', 'AD30'],
    data: [87, 24, 76, 5, 57, 67, 43, 47, 56, 19, 20, 32]
}];
```

I would like to see the name of each item (Southwest, Delta, AA..) displayed as the label on the y-axis and the name of each 'partner' (A1, B2, C3...), displayed in each bar with the corresponding data determining the length of the bar.  So in this case Southwest would have 5 bars, Delta would have 2, AA 6, China Air 5 and Air Mexico 12.  With each bar labeled by the partner name.

I believe the problem is that highcharts doesnt support having a different number of series for each particular item. I don't want to put zeros to make all charts have an equal amount of series (bars).

So far the only alternative I see is to create a separate highchart bar chart for each item in mockData and try to make it look like 1 continuous graph.

Additionally I'm a bit worried about rendering 1 large bar chart for this since some of the items can have as many as 250 partners...so this chart will be quite large.

I hope this question is easy enough to understand, but I can clarify any confusion.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how this chart suppose to look, so I suggest to use [grouped categories](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories) plugin, to display data: http://jsfiddle.net/TFhd7/754/

However, as you said, it's not a problem to render 1000 of bars, but readability of the chart will be very bad (just multiplicated data, see: http://jsfiddle.net/TFhd7/755/ )

Sample code for Highcharts:

```
var categories = [],
  seriesData = [];

$.each(mockData, function(i, item) {
  categories.push({
    name: item.name,
    categories: item.partners
  });
  seriesData = seriesData.concat(item.data);
});

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: "container",
    type: "bar"
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    data: seriesData
  }],
  xAxis: {
    categories: categories,
    labels: {
      x: -4
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Great, thank you!  This is exactly what I'm looking for.

With the plugin is it possible to get rid of the column with secondary labels (all the names of the partner names)?

Comment: Not quite, but I appreciate you taking you time to respond.  Not being able to get rid of that middle chart label was a bit of a deal breaker for me so I ended up going with a multiple highchart instance approach.  I wanted to get rid of the middle label area for display purposes only but still keep the name of the partner in the hover.  I dont think the plugin supports what I need to accomplish.  Thanks for your help